# setting scene unit size for very small scale

Tags: scale, scene, units

Coming from a Softimage background - attempting to using Blender for a cellular explainer. It makes sense to use Micrometers as a length unit, so in the SCENE I have set:

- *Unit System* to: *Metric*
- *Length* to: *Micrometer*

So far so good.

Bearing in mind I have to get to 1 nanometer scale which is 1000th of 1 micrometer, so I can (and have) set the unit scale to  0.0001 and adjust the camera clipping planes slightly so I can see my objects ok. This just about makes the scene 'big enough' to view 1 nanometer, however if you make the scene unit scale to 0.00001 my 0.001 µm '1 nanometer' sized (dimension) object suddenly becomes 10000 times bigger in its dimension (the setting in dimension pings to 10µm).

This breaks all meaningful size/dimensions set in the scene.

1. Is this a bug/glitch?
2. Is there a better approach of setting scene sizes for this type of scene/visualisation, from 10 microns to 1 nanometer?

Comment: Oh, this looks like a nice bug... :). And when you change the unit scale back to 0,0001 all dimensions are correct again. Really weird.

Comment: @Jachym Michal - Ahh.. thats what I thought - thanks for confirming. I Will try to work around this.